# Includes directory in build path

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I want to be able to add a directory containing a bunch of files to my project. This directory will need to be included in the build. I then need to be able to get the path of this directory at runtime.

Is there a way I can do this?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you talking about resources? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the directory with all the files and set the property of each files as follows. This will make sure that all the files will be copied to running directory.

- `Build Action` : Content
- `Copy Always` : Copy Always (Depends on you need)

**Access Files in the directory at run time**

You can access using relelative path

```
bool isFileExisit = File.Exist("DirectoryName/FileName");
```

Access File with full path

```
String fullFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "DirectoryName", "FileName");
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the folder to the project, and set `Copy to output directory` property to true.

To reference application path use `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the files to your project and mark them as content files.

Then, to access them at run-time use the following code snippet:

```
    string[] resourceNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
        foreach (var resourceName in resourceNames)
        {
            if(resourceName.StartsWith("<assembly short name>.<directory name>"))
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
```